# problem in laravel route on tackling the response of payment gateway

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm using laravel and integrate the payment gateway.when i send the post request then after success or cancellation ,it redirect the referece id like this
http://localhost/multi_vendor/user/paypal/return?flwref=FLW-MOCK-d4f7572650fbe61ecff7fb17a7129859&txref=rave-bxw7c98dymo8so0kwosco0wwscs8ogc
so how can tackle it in laravel?

I made route for this

```
Route::get('/paypal/return', 'User\PaypalController@payreturn')->name('user.payment.return');
```

Comment: Inside of your `public function payreturn($request, $request), you can access the query string values via `$request->input('flwref)` and `$request->input('txref')`. What exactly is your issue here? You haven't really explained what's going wrong/what problems you're having with this.

Comment: public function payreturn(Request $request){
    dd($request);
}

Comment: Sir i'm handling this response by using 
public function payreturn(Request $request){
    dd($request);
}

but when url redirect its show me the 
"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: Enable logging... You should only see that screen in `production`. Set these in your `.env`: `APP_ENV=local` and `APP_DEBUG=true`. Also, make sure you're importing `Request` in your controller via `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` (all Controllers should have this)

Comment: Thanks for you assistance but i'm not complete it after a lot effort
please check this video

Comment: http://webhookdanish.000webhostapp.com/video.html
Please sir guide me
I'm stuck wit this issue from 3 days

Comment: @TimLewis
Sir these are file link
http://webhookdanish.000webhostapp.com/controller.txt
http://webhookdanish.000webhostapp.com/route.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can create a route as you write above:-

```
Route::get('/paypal/return', 'User\PaypalController@payreturn')->name('user.payment.return');
```

Then in User\PaypalController Controller method payreturn, you can do as following:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class PaypalController extends Controller
{

public function payreturn(Request $request)
{
//Here you can get the response request values
$ref = $request->flwref;
$TxRef = $request->txref;

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you assistance
Sir as you say,I'm same adopt the procedure but it's can't work for me till now.

Comment: Route
_______

Route::post('/flutterwave/submit', 'User\PaypalController@process')->name('user.flutterwave.submit');
Route::get('/flutterwave/return', 'User\PaypalController@flutterwave')->name('user.flutterwave.return');

Comment: my controller
__________________

Comment: My Controller
_____________
http://webhookdanish.000webhostapp.com/controller.txt  
MY route
_______________________________________
http://webhookdanish.000webhostapp.com/route.txt

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't understand well your question, but let me try.

Possible appointments:

- if your route is like localhost/multi_vendor/user/paypal/return, you must represent all steps in route file, something like `Route::get('/multi_vendor/{user}/paypal/return,[...])`. If you are already using somethink like it or a group with prefix, ignore it;
- if you wish to redirect, you could use `return redirect('yourCompleteUrl')` in your controller or in route file;
- if you wish to retrieave the parameters Tim Lewis anserwed what you need:

```
    public function payreturn(Request $request)
    {
        $flref = $request->input('flref');
        $txref = $request->input('txref');
    }
```

Comment: Sir what you are saying are right but my issue is not solved
Please guide me a little bit
http://webhookdanish.000webhostapp.com/video.html
http://webhookdanish.000webhostapp.com/route.txt
http://webhookdanish.000webhostapp.com/controller.txt

Comment: Just to me understand your flow: `public function process(Request $request){...}`  will processe the payment with the curl code; If success, it will skip `if(!$transaction->data && !$transaction->data->link)` and in the last line of method it will redirect to the url previously setted in `$redirect_url = action('User\PaypalController@payreturn');` and `'redirect_url'=>$redirect_url`.
I'm wrong about this flow?

Comment: If I'm not wrong:
I'm taking the /multi_vendor/ is part of your default url, and I saw the user group in routes. What happend is that you is not propagation of url paramenters.
Try attach them to the route:
      

 public function payreturn(Request $request){
        //dd($request);
        return redirect()->route('user-dashboard',['flwref'=>$request->flwref, 'txref'=>$request->txref])->with('success','Vendor Account Activated Successfully');
    }
   Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: It's hard to help you with we do not understand your real problem. Try to reformulate your question a little bit, please.

Comment: I just want to get the get parameters that returned by payment gateway

Comment: If you want to get them in payreturn method, my answer will be enough. If you wish to get in the dashboard, you should to pass them when redirect again, to do so my previous comment may help.

Comment: Everything is working fine.I just want to get the parameters that is returned by payment gateway which i want to access in returned url which define by the process function $redirect_url = action('User\PaypalController@payreturn'); b maybe you not see the video.Please see the video it's may clear you 
http://webhookdanish.000webhostapp.com/video.html

Comment: The video really helps. I couldn't watch it before, but seems to me that read parameters is not your problem. Something happend when redirect back to your application. Could you post your laravel log file for this error?
I'm not sure if csrf protection take part in it, but if so in VerifyCsrfToken middleware set this route in  `protected $except = [ ];`

Answer (score 0):

@darnish manzoor just add your url callback rootverto verifycrsf token

if your redirection url is /ravecallback, just add it and it will stop giving you method not allowed

```
protected $except = [
        '/ravecallback'
  ];
```